# Why was my site rejected for Google Adsense?

Tags: google, google-adsense

I have a 3 year old blog and its got around 16 articles/tutorials about some programming problems and solutions. It's getting pretty much a lot of view lately so I decided to apply for a google adsense account. When I first applied via blogger, google replied with the following statement:

```
Page Type: In order to participate in Google AdSense, publishers' websites
and application information must satisfy the following guidelines:

- Your website must be your own top-level domain (www.example.com and not
www.example.com/mysite).
- You must provide accurate personal information with your application
that matches the information on your domain registration.
- Your website must contain substantial, original content...
```

So, as I understood it, I decide to buy a domain and point my blogger blog to that new naked domain.
and here is the newly bought domain where all the contents of my old blog resides.
http://***.com/

I reapplied, hoping that this time, I will make the cut. But then I got this reply

```
Further detail:

Unable to review your site: While reviewing http://www.***.com/, we
found that your site was down or unavailable. 

We suggest you check whether there was a typo in the URL submitted. When
your site is operational, you can resubmit your application with the
correct site by following the directions below.
```

I'm a bit disappointed. Maybe I did something wrong with DNS configuration or something. But you can clearly see that my site is fully functional. I heard that google sends robots to crawl on to the site etc. It's just sad because I invested on a domain name, and now I can't even find ways to earn from it. Any tips?

Comment: 'cause... 3 years old, 16 articles??? Is it really original content?

Comment: I dont write on a daily basis.. And I only write stuff that I am likely to forget and that might be of help to other people on the internet.. :( y u flame so much?

Comment: Voting to close. You've already been told why the site was rejected. It was down *when they looked*. You say it's operational *right now*. Those two events have no relation. If the site is functioning now, then go ahead and resubmit.

Comment: I did resubmit several times, but I still keep on receiving the same feedback. You think I'd post it here if I didn't resubmit several times? nvm.. I'll get help somewhere else. :(

Comment: In the world of flames, that was an icecube. Many, many people come here with this question. Out of several billion pages that have been written on the subject 16 articles would have to be really exceptional to interest Google, or anyone else.

Comment: you are mean.. no wonder.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem too with my website which was not accepted for Google Adwords. In my case the problem was that the CMS system I was using had a bug and did not set the HTTP headers correctly. The browsers did not complain and the normal Google bot didn't have a problem either. Only the one they use to check the eligibility I know that the Google bots which are used to check the eligibility have sometimes problems too when you have a redirect right on the domain root. They give you then the wrong message that the website would not be available.